# Which is faster: using a global, pass by value, using a pointer?

Tags: c, performance, pointers, global-variables

I am wondering about performance/speed in c as to which is faster: using a global, pass by value, using a pointer?

I have a program which i want to write which is going to take a while to execute and i want it to be as fast as possible. I do know some of the efficiency "tricks" in C, but am unsure about this one. E.g. if it is faster to just use globals, then I'd be inclined to use "more" globals if you catch my drift...

Thanks

Comment: keeping the question aside... I don't think that change will make your current program significantly faster!

Comment: C is basically a fast language ; as pinkpanther said, it is not an important point. In my opinion, just don't use globals

Comment: These kind of vague question have been asked so many times before. This depends on a lot of factors, your platform, your code, the mood of the compiler... Possible duplicate of [C: Which is faster, accessing global variable or passing a pointer to the function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3948718/c-which-is-faster-accessing-global-variable-or-passing-a-pointer-to-the-functi)

Comment: Why not benchmark it yourself?

Comment: I saw that Q&A when making this Question, but didn't feel like it had really been answered. So, i thought if the question was asked in a different way it might yield different/better answeres.

Answer (score 0):

It depends very much on the machine, the type of the variable, how you use it inside the function and outside it, whether it is `const` or `volatile`, the compiler, the flags you pass to the compiler, etc.

You can't optimize without a program to optimize and a system to optimize it for.

(Disclaimer: I don't have real-world expertise on the matter)